# How do I use jQuery to insert PHP tags through the DOM?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Here is what I'm trying to do...

```
$("div").prepend("<div id='comment-number'><?php the_comment_number(); ?></div>");
```

Is there some way to get this to work?

```
<div class="gallery-item">
  <div class="comment-number"><!--?php echo htmlspecialchars(the_comment_number()); ?--></div>
  </span>
  <span class="gallery-icon">
    <a href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/attachment/fff/"><img src="http://mysite.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/fff-150x150.gif"></a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

PHP is executed on the server, but JavaScript code (jQuery) is executed later, in the web browser. For that reason, PHP can produce JavaScript code, but JavaScript can't produce PHP code.

The `<!--?` in your posted output shows that something is filtering our your PHP code. So the problem isn't your PHP code, it's that you're not actually executing PHP code. If it's a `.js` file, PHP almost certainly can't be included.

If PHP were being evaluated (*ex.* if this were in a `<script>` tag in a `.php` file), this should produce valid JavaScript code that will do what you want:

```
$("div").prepend("<div id='comment-number'><?php echo htmlspecialchars(the_comment_number()); ?></div>");
```

Comment: I tried this code but nothing shows up between the divs. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Where are you putting this code? The PHP tags are being filtered out, that's not ordinary behaviour.

Comment: Whatever system this is in is apparently filtering the PHP. That's the problem, not your code.

Comment: I'm not sure what system it is but the software is WordPress if that makes a difference.

Comment: @J82 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1610/discussion-between-jeremy-banks-and-j82)

Answer (score 3):

1) php is SERVER side scripting
2) javascript is CLIENT side scripting (generally)

so this is what happens:
1) User opens up your page http://example/
2) Your CLIENT sends GET request to http://example/ server
3) Apache (given you run on it) captures the request, based on the server config approaches index.php (index.html, etc). If php is installed, your index.php will be parsed by mod_php module
<<<< this is where SERVER side scripting is activated
4) outcome of the parsing of index.php will be then transferred back to CLIENT
5) CLIENT will digest the outcome received by SERVER
6) If there are javascript calls, those are executed either immediately OR when document is loaded (based on approach)

That's it. Here normal request life ends.

NOW if you want your page to dynamically update some parts of it, here is how you do that:
1) Usually to update your page dynamically, you would use AJAX approach. When AJAX request is created, 2-7 happens again, but this time the caller is your ajax process and information which is received is sent back to that process to decided what to do with it.
Okay, some coding:

1) index.php

```
<!-- include jquery, etc //-->
<div id="comments"></div>
<script>
    function fetch_comments(){  
        $.get("ajax.php", null, function(data)){
            // this is called, when response from SERVER is received
            $("#comments").prepend(data);
            setTimeout("fetch_comments", 5000); // fetch again in 5 seconds
        }
    }
$(document).ready({
    fetch_comments();
});
</script>
```

2) ajax.php

```
<?php
//fetch comments, return them for CLIENT
echo "<p>Comment on " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "<br />Lorem Ipsum</p>";
```

This should help you understand the whole process. Did not test the code, but should be quite ok.

Answer (score 1):

do a `.ajax()` query to PHP script that will provide you value of `the_comment_number();` and put result to comment-number by `$("#comment-number").prepend(result);` on success event in ajax query.

Remebmer that PHP script have to have connection to database and pass to it all variables you need (like entity id, article id, page etc.). You can do it by GET or POST.

Request is sended by browser so session/cookies will be the same unless you changed it in current request.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed on the server side so you cannot call it from javascript

You can try something like this which will render once the page loads

```
$("div").prepend("<div id='comment-number'>"+ <?php the_comment_number(); ?> +"</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add the value directly to the template instead of using javascriot? eg:

```
<div class="gallery-item"> 
    <div class="comment-number"><?php echo (the_comment_number());?></div>
 ...
</div>
```

Also you have a `</span>` tag with out matching `<span>` tag in your example.

Answer (score 0):

As already told, you can't produce or call php code from javascript directly(you need to make an ajax call or form submit). You need to make ajax call using jquery to fetch the comment number and then update it into div.

However, you may want to look at this library - http://www.phplivex.com/ .It may help you in doing things your way. It allows you to call user defined php functions in javascript using AJAX internally.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through this disccussion and from what i understand you want to acheive.. You gotta figure how your page is served. If it is an .php file that is serving the content, then you wont need Javascript at all and could get your function call to work by adding the function between the div as so..

```
<div class="comment-number"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(the_comment_number()); ?></div>
```

Assuming you don't have access to the .php or if its a .html/htm page that serves the content then your only bet would be to use ajax. That is make an ajax call to a php file(on the same domain) that makes your function call and echos the comment no. The Ajax will retrieve the echo'd comment no. which you can append/prepend to the desired